# What is a good way of printing out an unordered map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a large textfile that contains 10000 rows of 2 ip address 
**"129.151.102.150 119.128.105.153"**

What this represents is that the first ip address has connected with the right one and so on. In this textfile there are ip addresses that have connected multiple times. So what I am trying to do is print out the top 10 ip addresses that have connected the most. My approach have been this way I fill the contents of the textfile in an unordered map. I then created a **struct** that contains all the data necessary for the task. Then I also created an object of class **priority_queue**. My problem is that when I try to print it out it does so but only the same ip address show up 10 times for example **output in console windows shows** **"129.151.102.150 : 1"**  10 times where the 1 represents that it connected once.

```
struct data_pq
{
    string key;
    unordered_map<string, char> v;

    data_pq()
    {
        key = "";
    }
    data_pq(string key, unordered_map<string, char> v)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->v = v;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const data_pq& leftop, const data_pq& rightop)
    {
        return leftop.v.size() < rightop.v.size();
    }


};

class kommunikation3_3{
private:

unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, char>> m;
priority_queue<data_pq>pq;

public:
kommunikation3_3(){}
~kommunikation3_3(){}

void readfile(string file_name)
{
    ifstream fin(file_name);
    string strRow;

    while (getline(fin, strRow))
    {
        istringstream iss(strRow);
        string ip1, ip2;

        getline(iss, ip1, ' ');
        getline(iss, ip2);

        //vad gör de här två rader?????????????
        m[ip1][ip2];
        m[ip2][ip1] = '-';

        fin.close();
    }

    //Denna loop pushar information om första o andra deleln:
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
        pq.push(data_pq(it->first, it->second));
    }
}


void print(int n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)//n=10
    {
        cout << pq.top().key << ":" << pq.top().v.size() << endl;
    }

    pq.pop();
}
};
```

My main looks like this

```
cout << "top ten connections" << endl;
kommunikation3_3 m;

m.readfile("ip3.txt");
m.print(10);
```

Comment: Your `for` loop prints this: "cout << pq.top().key << ":" << pq.top().v.size() << endl;". There's nothing there that uses the loop index variable, `size_t i`, as such this will always print the same thing on every iteration of the loop. Your overall logic is quite tangled, so it's not clear what the loop should be printing, but that's why you see the same thing printed, every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `for` loop inside your `print` function `pq` doesn't get modified, that's why you get the same thing 10 times. Move the `pq.pop()` into the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on that. The readfile function was weird also but I managed to change it.